# Add text to the beginning of each line using Powershell

Tags: powershell

I'm using Powershell to export users to a CSV. Everything works fine but I would like to add commands for Live@edu to each line for import. The text I would like to add is "Add,Mailbox," before each line. Can this be done before the export-csv? Thanks in advance.

Here is the export code:

```
$CSV = @()
get-qaduser -searchroot 'OU=Test Live,DC=domain,DC=edu' -sizelimit 0 | foreach-object {
    $attributes = get-qaduser $_ | Select-Object Name,Mail,givenName,sn,displayName
    $CSV += $attributes
}
$CSV | export-csv -path "c:\test.csv" -encoding unicode -notypeinformation
```

Comment: So you want to add two new fields to each row? Or change the contents of the first field in each row?

Comment: 2 fields would be nice. Sorry but this is my first attempt at Powershell so I'm kind of new. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this, it adds two new columns (properties), Action (add) and Resource (mailbox) for each user object:

```
Get-QADUser -SearchRoot 'OU=Test Live,DC=domain,DC=edu' -SizeLimit 0 | Select-Object @{Name='Action';Expression='Add'}},@{Name='Resource';Expression='Mailbox'}},Name,Email,GivenName,LastName,DisplayName | Export-Csv -Path c:\test.csv -Encoding Unicode -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: No dice, but very close. It did add the 2 extra columns for Action and Resource but the fields were empty before each user.

Comment: AHAHA!! I see it now! It was simply missing the { token on the left of the expression value! Thanks a million Shay! {'Add'}}and {'Mailbox'}}

Answer (score 1):

This should produce tw new fields on the front of each row. Can't test it right now though:

```
$CSV = @()
get-qaduser -searchroot 'OU=Test Live,DC=domain,DC=edu' -sizelimit 0 | foreach-object {
    $attributes = get-qaduser $_ | Select-Object @{n='Add';e='Add';}, @{n='Mailbox';e='Mailbox'},Name,Mail,givenName,sn,displayName
    $CSV += $attributes
}
$CSV | export-csv -path "c:\test.csv" -encoding unicode -notypeinformation
```

Comment: Any reason | Select-Object Add,Mailbox,Name,Mail,givenName,sn,displayName wouldn't work just a well?

Comment: Actually now that you mention it, none that I can think of. Just habit to do it that way.

Comment: Thanks for the input guys, but I'm afraid neither worked. The first method using : @{n='Add';e='';}, @{n='Mailbox';e=''}, returned the error Select-Object : Key "expression" cannot have an empty string value. The second method of just using Add,Mailbox, simply put empty fields. I am reading AD attributes so I guess when it went to AD and didn't see an Add or Mailbox attribute it returned null.

Comment: So you are saying that your AD objects have a field on them called 'Add'?

Comment: No there are no attributes labeled Add or Mailbox. These are just the 2 commands that Live@edu needs when importing a CSV for mailbox creation. For example, if I wanted to delete a mailbox the CSV would need to be formatted: Delete,Mailbox,Name,Mail,givenName, etc.

Comment: Aah, I understand now. In that case, I recommend that you accept Shay's answer since it should do what you need. I'll update mine to reflect this as well.